# Where is `USERNAME_FIELD` defined in Django source code?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I found below in **[Django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9652a118ce8c1cbe1f7cf7a4423adb7c5c50757d/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L73)**

```py
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
    ...
        def get_username(self):
        """Return the username for this User."""
        return getattr(self, self.USERNAME_FIELD)
    ...
```

I searched out the whole Django source code, but did not find out where the **`USERNAME_FIELD`** was defined.

Can anyone help on this please?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L377
USERNAME_FIELD was defined in  AbstractUser

Comment: but `USERNAME_FIELD` is already used in `class AbstractBaseUser` who is the parental class of `class AbstractUser`.  it must be defined either within `class AbstractBaseUser` or earlier. But I did not see that.

Comment: Why do you think it needs to be defined somewhere else?
These are abstract classes, so they don't need to have these declarations. @YanTian
USERNAME_FIELD is only defined here

Comment: understand now. I forgot some basics that every attribute did not need to be declared (`USERNAME_FIELD= None` for example) firstly before they could be used (`self.USERNAME_FIELD`).

Comment: @YanTian can u mark this answer as correct one?

Answer (score 1):

You can find `USERNAME_FIELD` in `AuthenticationForm` class of django which inherites `forms.FORM` class of Form Api.

It is also defined in `models.py` in `AbstractUser` class, refer [Django GitHub Code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d795259ea96004df0a2469246229a146307bcd2c/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L377).

It is given in `constructor` method that is `__init__()` of `AuthenticationForm`.

From Django original Code:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Base class for authenticating users. Extend this to get a form that accepts
    username/password logins.
    """
    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'current-password'}),
    )

    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
    }

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
        The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
        """
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set the max length and label for the "username" field.
        self.username_field = UserModel._meta.get_field(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        username_max_length = self.username_field.max_length or 254
        self.fields['username'].max_length = username_max_length
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['maxlength'] = username_max_length
        if self.fields['username'].label is None:
            self.fields['username'].label = capfirst(self.username_field.verbose_name)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username is not None and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data

    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        """
        Controls whether the given User may log in. This is a policy setting,
        independent of end-user authentication. This default behavior is to
        allow login by active users, and reject login by inactive users.

        If the given user cannot log in, this method should raise a
        ``ValidationError``.

        If the given user may log in, this method should return None.
        """
        if not user.is_active:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',
            )

    def get_user(self):
        return self.user_cache

    def get_invalid_login_error(self):
        return ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
            code='invalid_login',
            params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
        )
```

Here focus on `__init__()` for get clearification about `USERNAME_FIELD`.

It is used for getting `user field` from `User` model or you can normally say for getting `username`.

You can find it in your local machine using below path:

**C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\forms.py**.

**Remember:** `AppData` folder will only appear if you select hidden items.